# how to find multiple occurring tags in a text with php?

Tags: php, find, preg-match, preg-match-all

i have a simple php example of using preg_match_all

```
$str = " 
Line 1: This is a string 
Line 2: [img] image_path [/img] Should not be [img] image_path2 [/img] included. 
Line 3: End of test [img] image_path3 [/img] string."; 

preg_match_all("~\[img](.+)\[/img]~i", $str, $m); 

var_dump($m);
```

and i would like it to return

```
array(
    [0] =>image_path
    [1] =>image_path2
    [2] =>image_path3
)
```

for some reason i don't get this result.

ant ideas?

Comment: Not sure why your tags are enclosed with [] but if you're just looking for php html parsing check out http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net for PHP.

Comment: This looks like BBCode, not HTML. But there's a PHP extension for that too: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
preg_match_all("~\[img](.+?)\[/img]~i", $str, $m); 

var_dump($m[1]);
```

The reason you need the `?` is to make it "non-greedy". With your code, it matches from the first opening tag to the last closing tag. The `+` and `*` operators are greedy by default, consuming as many characters as possible. The `?` modifier stops this behaviour.

You need to dump `$m[1]`instead of `$m` since `preg_match*` also matches the entire matched string, not just marked captures.

Live example: http://ideone.com/vXk9W